# bootstrap modal and datepicker show events

Tags: events, modal-dialog, show, datapicker

When click on datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), his SHOW event fires, but the modal's SHOW.BS.MODAL fires too. Whhere is a problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ArrDate')
.datepicker()
.on("show", function(event){
    alert("Q");
});

$("#dlg3000to3100")
.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    alert("W");
});

$("#dlg3000to3100")
.modal("show");
});
```

example[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GU2St/)

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

It seems to be a bug (or feature?) of the datepicker. What you can do is to prevent the `show.bs.modal` event reaching the dialog.

```
$('#ArrDate').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will detect the event at the datepicker level and stop the event propagation, so `show.bs.modal` will not 'bubble up' to the dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Another work around is to swap the **show.bs.modal** with **shown.bs.modal** on modal event.

```
modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
               // Do something
            });
```

however if it is not possible to swap show with shown or hide with hidden use the namespace check

```
modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    if (e.namespace === 'bs.modal') {
         // Do something
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, caused by the datepicker watching for a show event.

One option is to use the shown event on the modal but this is not ideal in all cases

```
$('#dlg3000to3100').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    // modal code in here
});
```

A more elegant solution is to check the namespace of the event

```
$('#dlg3000to3100').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    if(event.namespace !== 'bs.modal') return;
    // modal code in here
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bzh75tww/